# Squid doesn't log client IP address

Tags: proxy, logging, squid

I can't get my proxy squid to log clients ip addresses.

I'm using :

```
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log common
client_netmask 255.255.255.0
log_ip_on_direct on
log_fqdn off
```

But in my logs :

> : - - [03/Jul/2011:10:29:30 +0000]
>   "CONNECT 0-8.channel.facebook.com:443
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 0 TCP_MISS:DIRECT

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check your log format option:

http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/logformat/

e.g:

```
logformat combined %>a %ui %un [%tl] "%rm %ru HTTP/%rv" %Hs %<st "%{Referer}>h" "%{User-Agent}>h" %Ss:%Sh
```